# How can I specify custom path for TestNG XML when calling it thorugh class

Tags: xml, selenium-webdriver, path, testng

I ma trying to call TestNG XML through class but it getting path problem.

It is finding specified XML in my workspace->Project folder>Root but My XML is not there and it is in sub folder of TestNG , So how can I specify here my own path to tell it that XML is here , I have written code :

```
public class Runnable {

public static void main(String[] args) {


     List<String> suitesList = new ArrayList<String>();
     TestNG testng = new TestNG();

        suitesList.add("Test.xml");
        testng.setTestSuites(suitesList);

        testng.run(); 

}
```

Comment: Have you given the full path xml in `suitesList.add()` method? I hope it will work if you give the full path.

Comment: @nitinchawda - thank you buddy , I was not aware that we can pass full path also , it works..:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per OP, the solution worked is as below:

Provided full path in the method

```
suitesList.add(<complete path to xml>);
```